# Operation and Control of EOD Bot

Tags: battlefield-3

Are there any other controls for the EOD bot, other than the forward/left/right/back for movement and left mouse button for using the torch?  It seems like there might be a way to raise or lower the torch, and to arm an MCOM is it just LMB click?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "interact" button (default <kbd>E</kbd>) can be used to arm MCOMs with the EOD bot.

The repair tool (fire key, default <kbd>Left Mouse</kbd>) can repair friendly vehicles, damage enemy vehicles, and also disarm/dispose of enemy explosives, such as C4.  It can also kill, just like the normal repair tool, although getting close enough to do so can be tricky.

You can "aim" the repair torch to an extent by moving your mouse, but there's no control for moving the torch arm around any more than that.

Comment: Cool, thanks for a quick answer.  I've been driving it around quit a bit and have also cut fences with it, and exploded a fuel tanker.  I've capped flags with it, but never armed an MCOM yet.  I've heard you can have a teammate strap some C4 to it and drive it up to vehicles or people and detonate it.

Comment: EOD bots can spot enemies as of the latest patch as well, that is worth mentioning.

Comment: Also, a little known fact to make the EOD bot more controllable, you can go into third person view using the normal button for vehicles. (this was not obvious to my circle of friends)